# Using Django, why would REMOTE_ADDR return 127.0.0.1 on a web server?

Tags: python, django

When getting the IP with `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` code. This works fine on the local system but when hosted on a web server the ip got is 127.0.0.1 - How can this be resolved?

Comment: How are the requests getting from the web server to the Django app?

Answer (score 10):

Your web server is probably behind a load balancer. You can try using request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].

Or better, look at the [django book, chapter 15](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter15/) - *What’s Middleware?* and *Reverse Proxy Support (X-Forwarded-For Middleware)* sections.

Comment: Note that the X-Forwarded-For middleware has been deprecated/removed from recent Django versions, as it was decided that it might give developers a false sense that the X-Forwarded-For header can actually be relied upon (which it can't). Easy enough to write your own; just be aware it can easily be spoofed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are behind a proxy and running apache as the webserver you could use mod_rpaf. The proxy only needs to send X-Forwarded-For or X-Real-IP headers.

http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/